# At what point does Devise move unconfirmed_email to email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Devise with `:confirmable` option enabled. I am also using `config.reconfirmable = true` and thus adding `unconfirmed_email` column to my user model.

From [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable):

> unconfirmed_email - An email address copied from the email attr. After
>   confirmation this value is copied to the email attr then cleared

However, when I create and log a user I get `nil` for the `unconfirmed_email` attribute, even though I don't confirm. The `email` field, on another hand, is not empty and contains the unconfirmed email.

When I log user object in my `after_create` callback, I have `unconfirmed_email: <email>`, `email: nil`. Which means that initially the user object is created with `unconfirmed_email` filled in, but then at some point (although before confirmation) moves to `email`.

So the question is, at what pointdoes Devise copies `unconfirmed_email` value to `email`, and why is it doing so before the email is confirmed.